# kafka consumers in consumer group not resuming messages after restart

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Hope you are having good day.

I have an issue with kafka consumers on kubernetes. I am running 3 replicas inside a consumer group
I have a topic with 3 partitions and 3 brokers with offsets replication factor set to 3. My offset in consumer group is set to earliest.

When I start the consumer group, all are working fine with each consumer replica taking different partition and processing the data.

Issue: When by any means if a consumer replica inside the consumer group "abc-consumer-group" restarts OR if a broker(leader) restarts, it is not resuming from the point where it stopped. It states that I am up to date and no messages I have to process.

Any suggestions please where to look at?

Tried increasing rebalance, heartbeat, session timeout on broker level, no luck.
And yes whenever any new consumer is added or removed to the consumer group rebalacing is taken care by kafka. I do see it happening but still not consumers are not resuming messages. It states nothing to process.

Comment: Maybe you really are up to date? Show your lag metrics across restarts

Comment: From consumer-groups.sh, I do see the lag still there.

Comment: I would triple check that auto.offset.reset is set to earliest and is not taking the default

Comment: I did check, it is indeed earliest.

Comment: Hi, there are different possible scenario, please share your code and configs and if you have override the enable.auto.commit or not